# Do multiplayer games use common server frameworks?

Tags: networking, multiplayer, mmo

I mean, does each game company develop its own chat server? Login server?

I'm not sure how massive multiplayer games work, I believe they each have a login/lobby server and game servers, which the login server puts players in until they fill up and then continues to the next one (I'll call this "scaling"). Does each company develop its own scaling algorithm?

*I'm not sure which tags I should put on, please help me with this.

Comment: What other games do might or might not be what's right for your situation and the particular game that you're making. Can you edit your question to tell us more about your project and its server needs? Have you encountered a problem that you think leveraging an existing server framework would help you solve? Do you need help implementing this, or finding an alternative solution?

Comment: There is no project, I'm just thinking about networking architecture design in multiplayer games

Comment: Ah. This site is for game developers to get help with developing games and mods. If help with a game development project isn't what you're looking for, then this might not be the best place to ask. Maybe try a discussion forum instead if you're looking for speculation about other games, rather than concrete solutions for the game you're developing.

Comment: This isn't a speculations discussion, I'm asking "How do you guys design your login and game creation methods? Does it differ from what big companies do? Is there a commonly used framework among mmo developers that handles these issues?", therefore I'm pretty sure it belongs here. Am I wrong?

Comment: "How can I design my login system" belongs here. Polling other developers for what various other games do, or asking for technology recommendations does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use World of Warcraft (wow) as an example:

The game client's first point of contact is the login server. This server processes your username and password, and interfaces with some form of use database, and handles privileges for certain users such as admins.

Once logged in, a list of available game servers, and player counts for each server is populated and presented to the user.

Once a game server is selected, the list of characters for the selected server is displayed (if any), and the option to join the server with the selected character, or create a new one.

When a group of character decides to run a dungeon or raid, another "lobby" server is joined which creates an instance of a smaller game server, in which the self contained dungeon exists. The players are then joined to this server to play the instance. When complete and all players leave, after a designated amount of time, the instance of that server is destroyed, unless it is a raid, in which case the progress (which bosses have been defeated) are saved to a database, along with the character names, game server name, and all participating players is saved to a database.

Later, if players rejoin that raid, the raid server is queried based on dungeon type/name, server name and character name. If an entry is found, an instance is created with the appropriate settings (defeated bosses missing). If not, a new instance is created and the players join as normal.

That about sums it up. Pretty much every multiplayer game uses this same basic architecture, though with differences specific to the type of game.

Even with smaller multiplayer environments on Steam, this principle still applies. Steam servers provide the framework for logins, but the developers will provide a lobby, which provides a list of available game servers. This precludes the need for "scaling".

Scaling, when necessary, is done rather naively, with performance/stress testing dictating the maximum number of players, which is then provided as configuration data as an upper limit. If the maximum number of players is reached in a login, or lobby server, players is placed in a queue, and informed to wait or try later.